# Set multiple alarms

Tags: android, android-intent

I have successfully set up an alarm app but the problem comes when there are multiple alarms. It overwrites the previously selected alarm.

What changes should I make to my `MainActivity.java` file, near the pending intent statement?

I searched online, they said use a for loop to increment the pending intent id , but it isn't working.

Any help would be great. Here is my code.`

```
public void add() {

    button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timepicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timepicker.getCurrentMinute());
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                **PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);**
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "the alarm is set for " + timepicker.getCurrentHour() + " : " + timepicker.getCurrentMinute(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myDb.insertRow(timepicker.getCurrentHour().toString(), timepicker.getCurrentMinute().toString());

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define different id for every pending intent, just make little change in the following line -

```
**PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);**
```

In stead of passing 1 just pass unique id for every different alarm.

```
public static int getAlarmId(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        int alarmId = preferences.getInt("ALARM", 1);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("ALARM", alarmId + 1).apply();
        return alarmId;
}
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: I am storing the alarm in a listview. can you edit the code for me ? so i will initialize a variable and increment it and set it as a unique id ? I am struggling since yesterday over this.

Comment: Yes increment will work fine, or you can use hhmmddmmyy int format like 1358080714 for 8th july at time 1-58 PM, so it will avoid duplicate alarms, but if you don't need any high level accuracy then go for increment only :)

Comment: it isn't working. I initialize a uniqueid variable =1, *PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, uniqueid, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); and then uniqueid++

Comment: Better to manage in SharedPrefences, like everytime you read the value increase value by one and again write it. So everytime you fetch, you will get a new value.

Comment: After initializing the unique variable also , it is overwriting my previously set alarm and only the last alarm set is ringing. What do i do ?

Comment: I have added code for getting unique alarm id every time, if still you are facing same problem, Kindly post your all related code to figure out the problem.

Comment: Hey thank you so much , it worked! Although i didn't put it in a function. I directly used the sharedpreferences in my onClick method and passed the alarmID in my pendingIntent. Multiple alarms are working now. Thankyou :)

Comment: and also there is spelling error in your return method, it should be alarmID and not alramID :)

Comment: Ohh, but you missed the bigger one, their should be a semicolon at the end also :)
Bye the way, Edited thanks :)